# Sans serif font to match with Palatino

Tags: fonts, pdftex, engineering

I really like to make my titles and subtitles different from the body text, so I often use sans serif font for the \section{} and \subsection{}. I started to use Palatino clone with `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`. To match with it, I saw some recommendations and came to this:

- Source Sans Pro
- Fira Sans

In both cases, I intend to use for the titles their semibold version. Are the good fonts to use with Palatino from the typography point of view? Any suggestions are also welcome.

My document purpose is for scientific/engineering paper.

Comment: Years ago I bought Palatino Sans just for the same reason.

Comment: I bought Palatino Sans too. Optima would be another good choice — both classics by Zapf. By the way, welcome to the site!

Comment: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwclassico/

Comment: For an Optima clone, `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epigrafica}
\usepackage[italic,nominus]{mathastext}`. See https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/epigrafica/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend Optima, by the same designer as Palatino, the great Hermann Zapf.  A clone of it, URW Classico, is available *gratis* [on CTAN.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classico)  The license allows only non-commercial use, so it is not included in TeX Live by default.

After you copy the files from CTAN to your local TeX tree (or install the OpenType fonts as system fonts) you can enable them in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale=1.0] % Or Palatino Linotype, etc.
\setsansfont{URW Classico} % Or Optima
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} % Or Asana Math
```

In PDFTeX, you would need to run `texhash` and `updmap-sys --enable Map=classico.map` to enable the PostScript font, then select the same fonts with

```
\usepackage{tgpagella, classico, inconsolata, newpxmath}
```

I often combine these fonts with Hermann Zapf’s math font, AMS Euler, or its free OpenType version, [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf).

Another that you might try is Gill Sans.  There is also a commercial font from Linotype named Palatino Sans.

Comment: Hmm... it tries to build a bitmap font for me with `pdflatex` (and it fails...). This is quite strange

Comment: @Rmano I’ve edited in the commands that should enable the font for you in PDFTeX. You might need to run them as root/Administrator.

Comment: @Davidslor thanks, it worked!

Comment: @Rmano I should have posted all the steps to install it to begin with.